# Node/Express execute initiation of the server on each request

Tags: node.js, express

When I initiate the app, I have something like this in my index file:

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
// ...
// other require statements

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
// ...
// other middlewares

require("./db");
require("./routes");

app.listen...
```

Now, I know that with each request to the server all the `app.use` middlewares are fired, but what happens to the require statements and how does it affect if require statement is at the top of the file or in the middle as in my example.

Comment: Top 2 lines are used to import dependencies which you have previously installed via NPM e.g. express and cors. They're required to be at the top of your file so that you can use them in subsequent sections in the same file e.g. `app.use(cors())`. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I'm aware of that, but this doesn't address my question.

Comment: The point I was trying to make is that you can't have the `use` statements preceding the `required` statements because what is to be used need to be imported first. Middleware packages are used once and used for each request where needed.

Comment: Require statements are not used exclusively for importing previously installed packages. If I'm in a need to split my app, I will need to import that file from another place and it might need to be loaded afterwards some initiation processes, like routes may need an app to pass on. But I'm not sure about middlewares, as far as I can tell they're also run in sync manner unless explicitly set otherwise.